How to validate these elements has the same value in Playwright typescript?
I have these elements in single page. I want to check using playwright that 17 alerts has same value on 17 alerts under the pie chart
see this image
I havent done anything yet as I am not good in programming but I am expecting to validate both elements has same value of 17
see attached image
TIA

Go ahead and select the elements by text content or use an await expect(yourLocator).toHaveText("17"). It's hard to help without the page and some code attempt.

hi @ggorlen, sorry I am not sure how to start the validation. But i amlooking for a dynamic approach as the element updates all the time.

What is the range of possible values? Again, you'll need to share the page or a reproduction of its markup to get help.

You can (and should) use assertions for that.
For example:
const expectedText = "17"

const locatorA = await page.locator("<your_locator_here>");
await expect(locatorA).toHaveText(expectedText);

const locatorB = await page.locator("<another_locator_here>");
await expect(locatorB).toHaveText(expectedText);

Another way, you can fetch the text of each element and assert that they are equals.

Hi,@I.sh. thanks. But i am looking for a dynamic approach as the element updates all the time. How can I do that?

Dynamic Approach.
As mentioned by I.sh. store the text of each element in a variable and then check they they equal.


const alert1Txt = await page.locator('your_locator').textContent();
const alert2Txt = await page.locator('your_locator').textContent();
expect(alert1Txt).toEqual(alert2Txt);



